# How to add rights to an user with olcAccess, in an OpenLDAP 2.4

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have an OpenLdap Server 2.4 running in my company and I need to permitt people to change their picture in one of our WebApplication.
The function is already present. People in LDAP just don't have any rights to write their own attributes (specially here the *"jpegPhoto"* attribute needed).

I found this in the Documentation

```
access to attrs=jpegPhoto
    by self =xw
    by * read
```

I don't know how to use theses lines. What command to use or something else.

If someone could help me in the way to process it could be great.

Thanks

Comment: You would like to know the *meaning* of these lines, or you are sure they will work and you simply would like to add them to your database configuration?

Comment: I understand these lines, I just don't know how to use them, with a command ? Add them to a file ? Which file ? I'm a bit lost

Comment: Are you using the old `slapd.conf` file for server configuration, or the new configuration layout `cn=config`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modifications you need to apply are simple, if you are using `slapd.conf` as the server configuration file, and a bit more complicated if you are using the new `cn=config` layout. Be careful, anyway, that:

> The older style slapd.conf(5) file is still supported, but its use is deprecated and support for it will be withdrawn in a future OpenLDAP release.

as stated in the OpenLDAP [documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html).

### 1) cn=config layout

You need to modify the configuration for the database you are using. Your OpenLDAP server may contain multiple databases, but you are interested only in the one that stores people data and their pictures. To list all your available databases, use:

```
slapcat -b cn=config
```

This command must be executed from the OpenLDAP server. It will read the file named `cn=config.ldif` in your [`slapd`](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html) configuration directory. In my case, it is located in

```
/usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif
```

Be careful that `slapcat -b cn=config` will work only if the shell user can read this file. In my case, the file is

```
-rw-------  1 ldap  ldap  680 10 mar 21:04 /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif
```

It belongs to user `ldap`, group `ldap` (they have been created during the OpenLDAP server installation). I have never set a password for user `ldap`, so:

**tl;dr** a way to read this file and to successfully run `slapcat -b cn=config` is to be `root`.

The output of `slapcat -b cn=config` is huge, but you can consider the last lines only, where the database you are interested in is listed. For example, it could be

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
```

This is, for example, the Distinguished Name (`dn`) of the database containing users pictures. You want to allow users to change their pictures.

You can modify the database configuration running (similarly to the previous case, you need write permissions on the file `cn=config.ldif`, so you could be `root` as before):

```
ldapmodify -f /path/to/yourfile -x -D "cn=config" -W
```

- `-f /path/to/yourfile` is your configuration file (see below);
- `-x` is Simple Authentication, it is needed if you are not using SASL;
- `-D "cn=config"` is the username you are using to enter the OpenLDAP database. There is usually a super-user for each single database (frequently called `Manager`), and a global super-user. The user named `cn=config` is the **global super-user**. You should have configured its password during the OpenLDAP server installation; if you don't have this password, you could be not able to modify the databases configuration;
- `-W` asks you to type the password for the user `cn=config`.

The configuration file, located in `/path/to/yourfile`, must be a plain text file formatted as follows:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=jpegPhoto
  by self write
  by * read
```

I would suggest to you to prefer `by self write` instead of `by self =xw` (which would not permit users to read their pictures). Be careful to put **two** spaces before `by`, as stated in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/490639).

You can now run again `slapcat -b cn=config` to check if the configuration has been modified, and also if the `olcAccess` statements are in the correct order. If not, you can delete them and add them again, knowing that each new `olcAccess` specification will be automatically put after the preceeding ones.

### 2) slapd.conf layout

If you are using the old `slapd.conf` configuration file, you simply need the write permissions to it. Usually it is:

```
-rw-------  1 ldap  ldap   2557 Dec  15  2016 slapd.conf
```

So, you can open it as `root`, with your preferred text editor. Identify the database section you want to modify (for example the one beginning with:

```
database        mdb
maxsize         1073741824
suffix          "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"
```

and simply add your lines at the bottom of this section, being careful if other `access` statements are already present. Again, I would suggest to use `by self write` instead of `self =xw`.

---

Regardless of your configuration, restart the OpenLDAP server (process `slapd`) after your modifications.

---

If you need further examples and/or clarifications, please consider:

- A `cn=config` [configuration example](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html#Configuration%20Example);
- [Access Control](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) for OpenLDAP databases;
- the [OpenLDAP site](http://www.openldap.org/), with the whole
  documentation.