# ldapsearch returns "No such object"

Tags: ldap, phabricator

I have an LDAP server and can successfully search for a user:

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -p 389 -b "dc=pieye,dc=org" "cn=Markus Proeller" -D "cn=admin,dc=pieye,dc=org" -W
Enter LDAP Password:
...

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

However if I try to perform the same search with my user I get the following output:

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -p 389 -b "dc=pieye,dc=org" "cn=Markus Proeller" -D "cn=Markus Proeller,ou=people,dc=pieye,dc=org" -W
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
# 
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=pieye,dc=org> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=Markus Proeller
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

I expect to get the same result with both binddn users. The background of my question is related to phabricator, as LDAP authentication fails there because it seems to expect valid output from the second command as well.

### Edit

The problem is related to LDAP user rights (see for instance [How to add rights to an user with olcAccess, in an OpenLDAP 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281171/how-to-add-rights-to-an-user-with-olcaccess-in-an-openldap-2-4)).
My problem was solved by using the following ldap.ldif file:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
-
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by 
dn="cn=admin,dc=pieye,dc=org" write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=pieye,dc=org" write by users read by * none
```

The file is applied by:

```
ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ldap.ldif
```

Comment: I am attempting to solve the exact same issue.  Please update your question if you've found the issue?